# Why the line with two origins is regular

Tags: general-topology

Define line with two origins as
Let $X$ be the union of the set $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ and the two-point set $\{p,q\}$. The line with two origins is the set $X$ topologized by taking as base the collection $\mathbb{B}$ of all open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ that do not contain $0$, along with all sets of the form $(−a,0)\cup\{p\}\cup(0,a)$ and all sets of the form $(−a,0)\cup\{q\}\cup(0,a)$, for $a>0$.

And define regular not need to be Hausdorff.

I've read the line with two origins is not Hausdorff but regular.

It's not Hausdorff, since $p$ and $q$ do not have disjoint neighbours.

But $X-\{p\}= (−\infty,0)\cup\{q\}\cup(0,\infty)$ is open (is it open?), then $\{p\}$ is a closed set, then if the space is regular, $q$ is a point not in the closed set $\{p\}$, then there are two disjoint neighbours containing $p$ and $q$ respectively, but that's impossible.

So where this goes wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Where did you read it was regular? (It isn't, as your argument shows. It's a $T_1$-space, a fortiori $T_0$, and "regular + $T_0$" implies Hausdorff.)

Comment: @DanielFischer In elementary topology problem textbook, It should be a mistake the author made.

Comment: Yes, mistakes happen.

Comment: @Cathy You should answer your own question to clear it from the unanswered queue. Alternatively delete the question.